# discord.js sqlite bind or column index out of range

Tags: node.js, sqlite, discord

So I am creating a bot for discord this code right here sends a PM to the person who joins the server:

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
    let guild = member.guild;
    console.log(`${member.user.username} has joined your server`);
        member.user.send('Welcome to my server!');
});
```

I am trying to create a database with sqlite to log the people that joins userID and username, heres what I have:

```
  client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
    let guild = member.guild;
    console.log(`${member.user.username} has joined your server`);
    sql.run(`UPDATE users SET userId = ${member.id} WHERE userId = ${member.id}`);
        member.user.send('Welcome to my server!');

    sql.get(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId = '${member.id}'`).then(row => {
            if (!row) {
            sql.run('INSERT INTO users (userId, username) VALUES (?, ?)', [member.id, 1, 0]);
        } else {
            sql.run(`UPDATE users SET username = ${member.user.username} WHERE userId = ${member.id}`);
        }

    }).catch(() => {
        console.error;
        sql.run('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (userId TEXT, username TEXT)').then(() => {
            sql.run('INSERT INTO users (userId, username) VALUES (?, ?)', [member.id, 1, 0]);
        });

    });
});
```

I am getting:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: SQLITE_RANGE: bind or column index out of range, whats wrong with the code? can anyone fix it?

Answer (score 1):

`sql.run('INSERT INTO users (userId, username) VALUES (?, ?)', [member.id, 1, 0]);` you are giving 3 values (member.id, 1 and 0) where you only have 2 (userId and username). Also, `sql.get()` doesn't return a promise so you can't use `.then()` . The 2nd parameter is the callback function which takes two arguments, possible error and the row(s), so instead your code should look like

```
sql.get('SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId = ?',[member.id] , (err,row) => {
        if (!row) {
        sql.run('INSERT INTO users (userId, username) VALUES (?, ?)', [member.id, 1]);
    } else {
        sql.run('UPDATE users SET username = ? WHERE userId = ?', [member.user.username, member.id]);
    }
})
```